# is there any way to simplify my code for matrix multiplication?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

```
public class J1_LAB08_1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int r1 = 5, c1 = 3;//rows and column for matrix a
    int r2 = 3, c2 = 4;//rows and column for matrix b
    int matrixA[][] = new int[5][3];//initialize matrix a
    System.out.println("Matrix A");
    for (int i = 0; i < matrixA.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixA[i].length; j++) {//create random single integer matrix
            matrixA[i][j] = ((int) (Math.random() * 10));
            System.out.print(matrixA[i][j]);//print matrix a
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Matrix B");
    int matrixB[][] = new int[3][4];
    for (int i = 0; i < matrixB.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixB[i].length; j++) {//create random single integer matrix
            matrixB[i][j] = ((int) (Math.random() * 10));
            System.out.print(matrixB[i][j]);//print matrix b
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
    int[][] matrixC = multiplyMatrices(matrixA, matrixB, r1, c1, c2);//pass variables to multiply matrices function
    printC(matrixC);//print matrix c

}
public static int[][] multiplyMatrices(int[][] matrixA, int[][] matrixB, int r1, int c1, int c2){//multiply the 2 given matrices and return the product
    int[][] matrixC = new int[r1][c2];//initialize the product matrix using row a and column 2 as its parameters
    for(int i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < c1; k++) {
                matrixC[i][j] += matrixA[i][k] * matrixB[k][j];//multiply using textbook formula
            }
        }
    }
    return matrixC;
}
public static void printC(int[][] matrixC) {//print the matrix
    System.out.println("A x B is: ");
    for(int[] row : matrixC) {
        for (int column : row) {
            System.out.print(column + "    ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

> is there any way to simplify my code for matrix multiplication?
> the resulting matrix should be 3 x 5 after multiplication
> any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you for your time and consideration.